# TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' when trying to sort a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to filter duplicate occurrence of number from the input string
If the string contains duplicate characters then it must print "Not a valid number , if the input is without duplicate characters it must print "Valid Number"
What is the correct way to check the duplicate occurrence

```
input_number = raw_input("Please input the number:")
print type(input_number)
if (int(sorted(input_number))):
    print "Not a valid number"
else:
    print "Valid number"
```

I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: the output of the sorted method is a list not an integer '(sorted(input_number))' and int take a string as argument

Comment: [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) returns a list, no matter what the type of the original sequence was.

Comment: What exactly is your question: the cause of the error, or a correct way to check for duplicate characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a `set` and measure its size.

```
if len(set(input_number)) != len(input_number):
    print "Not a valid number"
else:
    print "Valid number"
```

If a string contains duplicates, converting it to its `set` equivalent will cause a reduction in size, so the `set` will not be of the same size as the `str`ing.

Answer (score 2):

`sorted()` returns a list and `int()` cannot take list as an argument. To accomplish what you want to do (check if input contains duplicates) is to do

```
set(input_number)
```

Then check if the size of set is equal to `len(input_number)`, you get the size of set simply by `len(set(input_number))`. If yes, all characters are unique. If not, some characters repeated and got cut off, because `set()` is like a set in mathematics, it only contains unique elements. So if not all the elements in `input_number` are unique, then the size of set would be smaller.

Whole code would be something like this:

```
input_number = raw_input()
if len(input_number) == len(set(input_number)):
    print "Valid number"
else:
    print "Not a valid number"
```

Answer (score 2):

To get duplicate items in list

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> st = "12456432"
>>> 
>>> [item for item, count in Counter(st).items() if count > 1]
['2', '4']
>>>
```

For you **Solution 1**

```
>>> if len([item for item, count in Counter(st).items() if count > 1]) > 0:
...     print "invaild"
... else: 
...     print "vaild"
... 
invaild
>>>
```

Another **solution 2**

List has count method it returns no of any string exist in list

```
>>> for item in st:
...     if st.count(item) > 1:
...         print "invailed"
...         break
...     else:
...         print "vailed"
... 
vailed
invailed
```